# Accessing former XP drive as second drive under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions, ntfs

Here's the basic rundown of the problem :-

- Machine formerly XP MCE
- Bought new 2TB SATA drive to replace existing 150GB SATA drive
- Installed Win7 RC on new drive
- Attached old drive to other SATA connector
- Win7 complains I don't have permissions to access folders on old drive

Anyone know what I need to do to render my old drive accessible so I don't lose my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take ownership of the folders. The process to do this is described in detail [here](http://www.blogsdna.com/2159/how-to-take-ownership-grant-permissions-to-access-files-folder-in-windows-7.htm)

Comment: Seriously? Isn't there a no-write way to do this?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/19888/accessing-former-xp-drive-as-second-drive-under-windows-7-without-chowning